# Page is wider and taller than viewport by default on mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have the following blank HTML template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this via localhost inside iOS Simulator Safari, I get this:

[image]

Notice the scrollbars, which hopefully indicate how much wider and taller the page is than the viewport. This is despite my `meta` tag placed in the head.

The same cannot be said for desktop Safari, only when run on mobile Safari like this.

Why is this so wide and tall by default, and how do I ensure it's no larger than the viewport by default, without adding a bunch of CSS?

Comment: Have you actually tested the webpage on real mobile Safari to check if this isn't just the simulator being weird? The same page in FF iPhone 6 responsive design mode doesn't have a long width or height.